# How to avoid a 'Series not callable error' when indexing

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

I'm trying to use a column in a dataframe as an index in the same dataframe using:

```
env_1b.set_index(env_1b[0], inplace=True)
```

but get a Series object is not callable error.

The column in question (`env_1b[0]`) is a column of datetime values. this worked previously with another similar dataframe, any ideas on what might be causing the error this time around?

Comment: Are you sure you're using `[]` and not accidentally `()` somewhere, or do you have an extra `()` hanging around your code where you shouldn't? That line _should_ work

Comment: Nope, doubled checked the code. I used 'env_1b.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)' higher up in the code to remove a previous index, not sure if that might have affected index functioning?

Comment: Since you said its a column of datetime values, maybe its a `dtype` mismatch (datetime as column value vs object as column name).

Comment: @Henry Yik thanks, I'll check that and give it a go again.